# How to get the list of error numbers (Errno) for an Exception type in python?

Tags: python, exception

For a specific Exception type (let's say for IOError), how can i extract the complete list of Errnos and descriptions like this:

Errno 2: No such file or directory

Errno 122: Disk quota exceeded

...

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ca9a85c36e09/Include/errcode.h

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the [error codes](http://www.ioplex.com/%7Emiallen/errcmpp.html) are different by platform, and the language of the user may be different, it is usually best to print the exception in the normal fashion.

However, if you really want the list:

*edit:*

for python2:

```py
import os
import errno
    
print {i:os.strerror(i) for i in sorted(errno.errorcode)}
```

for python3:

```py
import os
import errno
from pprint import pprint

pprint( {i:os.strerror(i) for i in sorted(errno.errorcode)} )
```

Prints (on OS X):

```
{1: 'Operation not permitted', 2: 'No such file or directory',
 3: 'No such process', 4: 'Interrupted system call',
 5: 'Input/output error', 6: 'Device not configured',
 7: 'Argument list too long', 8: 'Exec format error',
 9: 'Bad file descriptor', 10: 'No child processes',
 11: 'Resource deadlock avoided', 12: 'Cannot allocate memory',
 13: 'Permission denied', 14: 'Bad address', 15: 'Block device required',
 16: 'Resource busy', 17: 'File exists', 18: 'Cross-device link',
 19: 'Operation not supported by device', 20: 'Not a directory',
 21: 'Is a directory', 22: 'Invalid argument',
 23: 'Too many open files in system', 24: 'Too many open files',
 25: 'Inappropriate ioctl for device', 26: 'Text file busy',
 27: 'File too large', 28: 'No space left on device', 29: 'Illegal seek',
 30: 'Read-only file system', 31: 'Too many links', 32: 'Broken pipe',
 33: 'Numerical argument out of domain', 34: 'Result too large',
 35: 'Resource temporarily unavailable', 36: 'Operation now in progress',
 37: 'Operation already in progress', 38: 'Socket operation on non-socket',
 39: 'Destination address required', 40: 'Message too long',
 41: 'Protocol wrong type for socket', 42: 'Protocol not available',
 43: 'Protocol not supported', 44: 'Socket type not supported',
 46: 'Protocol family not supported',
 47: 'Address family not supported by protocol family',
 48: 'Address already in use', 49: "Can't assign requested address",
 50: 'Network is down', 51: 'Network is unreachable',
 52: 'Network dropped connection on reset',
 53: 'Software caused connection abort', 54: 'Connection reset by peer',
 55: 'No buffer space available', 56: 'Socket is already connected',
 57: 'Socket is not connected', 58: "Can't send after socket shutdown",
 59: "Too many references: can't splice", 60: 'Operation timed out',
 61: 'Connection refused', 62: 'Too many levels of symbolic links',
 63: 'File name too long', 64: 'Host is down', 65: 'No route to host',
 66: 'Directory not empty', 68: 'Too many users',
 69: 'Disc quota exceeded', 70: 'Stale NFS file handle',
 71: 'Too many levels of remote in path', 77: 'No locks available',
 78: 'Function not implemented',
 84: 'Value too large to be stored in data type', 90: 'Identifier removed',
 91: 'No message of desired type', 92: 'Illegal byte sequence',
 94: 'Bad message', 95: 'EMULTIHOP (Reserved)',
 96: 'No message available on STREAM', 97: 'ENOLINK (Reserved)',
 98: 'No STREAM resources', 99: 'Not a STREAM', 100: 'Protocol error',
 101: 'STREAM ioctl timeout', 102: 'Operation not supported on socket'}
```

Comment: +1 I know how to print an exception :) but the link was very useful thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Do you mind removing the print exception part so that I can choose it as an answer? I also have to edit the question now that I know what it is all about.

Answer (score 6):

I fear those come straight from the standard C library, so you'll have to look it up in your system documentation. (GLibC, Microsoft, UNIX…)

Comment: thanks.. You mean the errnos could be different for the same error (e.g file not found) on different OSs?

Comment: Yes, they are. A couple dozen should be similar in all UNIX-derived systems (such as Linux, BSD and Mac OS X) but most will be different, even in different versions of the same system. If you add Windows to the equation, all bets are off. You shouldn't rely on those numbers at all. In fact, you're better off using the `errno` module to translate the numbers into identifiers (ENOENT, EPERM...) as others suggested.

Comment: Excellent point:  _I fear those come straight from the standard C library_.

Answer (score 6):

As others said, you should check `<errno.h>` of your system.

If you want to do it in python:

```
import errno
print errno.errorcode
```

output would be

```
{1: 'EPERM', 2: 'ENOENT', 3: 'ESRCH', 4: 'EINTR', 5: 'EIO', 6: 'ENXIO', 7: 'E2BIG', 8: 'ENOEXEC', 9: 'EBADF', 10: 'ECHILD', 11: 'EDEADLK', 12: 'ENOMEM', 13: 'EACCES', 14: 'EFAULT', 15: 'ENOTBLK', 16: 'EBUSY', 17: 'EEXIST', 18: 'EXDEV', 19: 'ENODEV', 20: 'ENOTDIR', 21: 'EISDIR', 22: 'EINVAL', 23: 'ENFILE', 24: 'EMFILE', 25: 'ENOTTY', 26: 'ETXTBSY', 27: 'EFBIG', 28: 'ENOSPC', 29: 'ESPIPE', 30: 'EROFS', 31: 'EMLINK', 32: 'EPIPE', 33: 'EDOM', 34: 'ERANGE', 35: 'EAGAIN', 36: 'EINPROGRESS', 37: 'EALREADY', 38: 'ENOTSOCK', 39: 'EDESTADDRREQ', 40: 'EMSGSIZE', 41: 'EPROTOTYPE', 42: 'ENOPROTOOPT', 43: 'EPROTONOSUPPORT', 44: 'ESOCKTNOSUPPORT', 46: 'EPFNOSUPPORT', 47: 'EAFNOSUPPORT', 48: 'EADDRINUSE', 49: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL', 50: 'ENETDOWN', 51: 'ENETUNREACH', 52: 'ENETRESET', 53: 'ECONNABORTED', 54: 'ECONNRESET', 55: 'ENOBUFS', 56: 'EISCONN', 57: 'ENOTCONN', 58: 'ESHUTDOWN', 59: 'ETOOMANYREFS', 60: 'ETIMEDOUT', 61: 'ECONNREFUSED', 62: 'ELOOP', 63: 'ENAMETOOLONG', 64: 'EHOSTDOWN', 65: 'EHOSTUNREACH', 66: 'ENOTEMPTY', 68: 'EUSERS', 69: 'EDQUOT', 70: 'ESTALE', 71: 'EREMOTE', 77: 'ENOLCK', 78: 'ENOSYS', 84: 'EOVERFLOW', 90: 'EIDRM', 91: 'ENOMSG', 92: 'EILSEQ', 94: 'EBADMSG', 95: 'EMULTIHOP', 96: 'ENODATA', 97: 'ENOLINK', 98: 'ENOSR', 99: 'ENOSTR', 100: 'EPROTO', 101: 'ETIME', 102: 'EOPNOTSUPP'}
```

Comment: thanks, this is not what I'm looking for. I mean the Errno when a specific python exception is thrown. For example 122 in 'IOError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded'.

Comment: ok i get it now. I thought Errnos are different for each type of exception. I mean I thought we could have 2 for IOError and also for IndexError for example. But it seems like its a global list. Am I right?

Comment: that's my understanding if the exceptions are using standard errno system symbols

Answer (score 4):

look for errno.h on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @the-wolf: I couldn't remember where the constants came from (os.strerror) and decided to place this here for future reference.

```py
def error_codes():
    from os import strerror as SE
    from errno import errorcode as EC
    for k in EC.keys():
        print("error: [Errno %i] %s [%s]"%(k,SE(k),EC[k]))
        #print("{%3i: %s}"%(k,EC[k]))
    del SE, EC
    try: del k
    except: pass

# Just print it
error_codes()
```