# What does [Errno 2] mean in python?

Tags: python, file

I was playing around with python, and I was trying to open a file. I accidentally made a typo, and got the expected error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tlesting.py'

It was supposed to be `testing.py` if you are wondering.

Of course, I expected the error, but I want to know the reason behind why `[Errno 2]` is included. I got curious, so I tried raising the error myself: `raise FileNotFoundError("This is a test")`, and got an output of: `FileNotFoundError: This is a test`, but no `[Errno 2]` anymore. Is this something to do with the current version of python or my current operating system?

Comment: It's a reference to the underlying operating system.

Comment: Further discussion: https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html and [how-to-get-the-list-of-error-numbers-errno-for-an-exception-type-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304934/how-to-get-the-list-of-error-numbers-errno-for-an-exception-type-in-python)

Comment: Why does the [Errno 2] not show when I raise the error intentionally?

Comment: Because no actual operating system error occurred, and therefore the `errno` variable was not set.

Comment: I think it's `open` that constructs the error message that contains `[Errno 2]` (using the correct number for the underlying operating system), not the `FileNotFoundError` class itself.

Comment: In Windows, the error ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND has the value 2.  Just that simple.

Comment: Don't put "resolved" messages in the question itself. Answers belong **only** in the answer section, not in questions. See also [How best to deal with self-answers edited into questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402010/how-best-to-deal-with-self-answers-edited-into-questions) on [meta], affirming that it's appropriate for such self-answers to be actively removed when found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the `[Errno 2]` tag, you can pass the appropriate error number as an explicit first argument:

```
>>> import errno
>>> raise FileNotFoundError("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: foo
>>> raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, "foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Common reason to this error is like the text says- file not found. mostly this will be because you try to access a filename without the path.

example:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Windows/System32/drivers'):
    for file in files:
        with open("hosts", "r") as file1:
            read_content = file1.read()
            print(read_content)
```

I get [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hosts'. This is because the filename exists in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, and the variable file1 contains only the value 'hosts'. In this example I need to join the current path to the filename....

Comment: OP question was about the presence of [Errno 2] which does not occur when raising exception by hand, not about the meaning of the error.